# Which regex codes would allow me to extract this specific text?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am using the `stringr` library in `R`. An extract of my R codes is shown below:

```
library(stringr)

...

hotelname <- url %>% html_nodes(xpath = './/*[@id="hp_hotel_name"]')  %>% 
html_text()
```

Above code gives me the following output:

```
"\nHotel\nCove Boutique Hotel (Adults Only)\n"
```

I need to extract only the second part: "**Cove Boutique Hotel (Adults Only)**"

I have tried the following but it's not working:

```
hotelname2 <- str_extract_all(hotelname, "(?<=[A-Z]\n)([^\n]*)")
```

Any idea what's wrong with my above regex codes?

Comment: Is this string always between the second and third \n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to extract the text between `\n` and `\n` ?

```
hotelname <- "\nHotel\nCove Boutique Hotel (Adults Only)\n"
sub('.*\n(.*)\n', '\\1', hotelname)

[1] "Cove Boutique Hotel (Adults Only)"
```

Answer (score 3):

Trim the \n whitespace on the ends and then remove everything up to and including \n

```
x <- "\nHotel\nCove Boutique Hotel (Adults Only)\n"
sub(".*\n", "", trimws(x))
## [1] "Cove Boutique Hotel (Adults Only)"
```

or scan in the \n separated fields and take the second:

```
scan(text = x, what = "", sep = "\n", quiet = TRUE)[2]
## [1] "Cove Boutique Hotel (Adults Only)"
```

or use trimws and then readLines:

```
readLines(textConnection(trimws(x)))[2]
## [1] "Cove Boutique Hotel (Adults Only)"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `stringr` anyway, one nice function is `str_squish()` which removes all whitespaces and newline characters etc.

```
hotelname2 <-  str_squish(hotelname)
```

I often pipe it in directly when scraping:

```
hotelname <- url %>% html_nodes(xpath = './/*[@id="hp_hotel_name"]')  %>% 
html_text() %>% str_squish
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `str_extract` with look ahead and look behind regex to get the desired result

```
hotelname <- "\nHotel\nCove Boutique Hotel (Adults Only)\n"

hotelname2 <- str_extract(hotelname, "(?<=Hotel\n).*(?=\n)")
```

Here, "?<=" tells code to look for text after "Hotel\n" and "?=" tells it to look for text before "\n". We add ".*" in between to return everything between the two matches.